# Bootstrapping regression coefficient for time series

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap, iid

One of the fundamental assumptions of bootstrap is that the samples are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d). This is the reason why it is difficult to bootstrap time-series because the random re-sampling destroys the time dependence structure of the original sample.

On the other hand, I know that bootstrapping can be used for 5% ~ 95% confidence interval of regression coefficients. Here's what I understand. Let $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, x_2, x_3, ...,x_n]$, and $\mathbf{y}=[y_1, y_2, y_3, ... y_n].$ And that the model I want to optimize is a linear model with $y_n=ax_n + b$

With bootstrap linear regression, I would do random resampling with replacement from the consistent indices of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, and then optimize the parameters $a$ and $b$. Because I fit the parameters from different portions of the data, the value of $a$ and $b$ are expressed in a range.

What I don't understand is that, the y-axis of a regression model is also dependent, but bootstrapping says that the samples need to be independent. And I've read many time that you can't use naive bootstrapping (other than block bootstrapping) with time series because it destroys the time dependence structure, but it seems that it's not the case if you want to fit regression coefficients on time series.

How is this possible? Is there a practical difference between bootstrapping the time series to get its C.I. of the mean, and bootstrapping the time series to get the C.I. of its regression coefficients?

Edit: CI of mean for time series would be something like this:

[image]

Whereas CI of regression model would be:

[image]

Comment: What is the CI of the mean? Are you not referring to the CI of the coefficients?

Comment: @user2974951 edited

Comment: Hi: I couldn't do answer justice here but I suggest reading the bootstrapping discussions of McKinnon. Also, I think, in some way, you may be referring to the pairs bootstrap but not realizing it. See Flachaire's papers for that. Note that the randomness in linear models is usually uncorrelated. This is why it's easier to bootstrap regression models than bootstrap time-series models. Also, ask yourself why you are boostrapping ? One usually does not bootstrap to obtain coefficients. Measures of uncertainty are more common.

Comment: I highly recommend this paper. http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/pub/faculty/mackinnon/rd-jgm-bootstrap-methods-2006.pdf. Also, if someone could tell me how to use latex to say "this link" and the person clicks on this link instead, it's appreciated.